# Add row to Multiindex dataframe using slicing

Tags: python, pandas, slice, multi-index

My dataframe looks like this

```
bid_ask.head(6)
Out[3]: 
                                close        high         low        open
timestamp           direction                                                
2018-08-16 21:00:00 bid           1.27156     1.27189     1.26899     1.27100
                    ask           1.27177     1.27270     1.27067     1.27210
                    volume     1254.00000  1254.00000  1254.00000  1254.00000
2018-08-16 22:00:00 bid           1.27131     1.27154     1.27112     1.27152
                    ask           1.27152     1.27195     1.27138     1.27173
                    volume      242.00000   242.00000   242.00000   242.00000
```

I am trying to perform the following operation on my dataframe to add rows using pd.IndexSlice as an analogue to the case with a simple dataframe index.

```
bid_ask.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 'mid'], :] = 0.5 * bid_ask.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, ('bid', 'ask')], :].groupby(level="timestamp").sum()
```

However, I get the following error:

```
KeyError: 'mid'
```

It seems that it expects "mid" to be in the dataframe rather than inserting it.

I can achieve the desired result by doing the following

```
 for i in bid_ask.index.get_level_values(0):

        bid_ask.ix[(i, "mid"), :] = 0.5 * (bid_ask.ix[(i, "bid"), :] + 
        bid_ask.ix[(i, "ask"), :])
```

This takes significantly longer though, especially if my dataset is large and is therefore undesirable.

How can I achieve this with slicing or any other faster alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `MultiIndex` and `concat`

```
new=0.5 * df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, ('bid', 'ask')], :].groupby(level="timestamp").sum()
new.index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([new.index, ['mid']])
pd.concat([df,new]).sort_index()
Out[81]: 
                             close         high         low         open
timestamp   direction                                                   
2018-08-161 ask           1.271770     1.272700     1.27067     1.272100
            bid           1.271560     1.271890     1.26899     1.271000
            mid           1.271665     1.272295     1.26983     1.271550
            volume     1254.000000  1254.000000  1254.00000  1254.000000
2018-08-162 ask           1.271520     1.271950     1.27138     1.271730
            bid           1.271310     1.271540     1.27112     1.271520
            mid           1.271415     1.271745     1.27125     1.271625
            volume      242.000000   242.000000   242.00000   242.000000
```